# Comparing large text fields for equality

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a `TEXT` field/column, potentially thousands of bytes of characters in length, how should I test equality between them? Should I simply do `t1.field = t2.field` in a query or should I store a hash of them for the purpose of an equality comparison?

Edit: The implied join here is not relevant. Consider that the two text fields could be of the same table. It's just that in my schema, it's not. The question could be reformulated as: "Is there a performance penalty for using the equality operator on extremely large text fields in a `where` clause?"

Also, is there a big hit for indexing such large fields? Are hashes a better route or does it not matter?

Comment: Is the column indexed? Does it have to be a complete match or partial match? Could you provide simplified sample data? Do you have to compare the column between different tables or is the data stored in one table?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you are doing.  Your question suggests a `join`.  And that seems like a bad idea on a `text` column.

Comment: Edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 3KB on the size of a column in an `INDEX`.  That is, this is *not* allowed:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    txt TEXT,
    INDEX(txt)   -- too big
);
```

So, indexing is out.

Perhaps you have two columns, txt1 and txt2?  And you want

```
WHERE txt1 = txt2
```

?  Sure, that is OK.  What is the performance penalty?  Think of it this way:  The cost of fetching the row(s) is higher than practically anything you can do with the columns.  That is, "No problem".

What about using a hash?  Don't bother.  The added complexity exceeds the cost of the large compare.  But...  You have not explained why you are asking.  Perhaps the real question is:

"How can I check to see if this big text string is already in that table?"  Now, without an index, it has to read the entire table and compare to each row.  This *is* costly.  This does lead to considering a hash.

Answer (score 1):

> The question could be reformulated as: "Is there a performance penalty for using the 
>   equality operator on extremely large text fields in a where clause?"

No, there is no performance PENALTY - it is just that any text comparison is AWFULLY slow to start with regardless what you do. Which is why there are special full text search mechanism and text search and index mechanisms in pretty much all databases.

Comparing a number is a super fast operation. Assuming a 32 bit size number or 64 bit size number that is a tiny processor operation. Comparing strings is that for every 8 chars and BRUTALLY higher if you talk unicode thanks to identity rules having to follow funny language specific rules (so not just comparing numbers). That is the baseline. A big size comparison thus is awfully slow.

And indices are only useful if you start at the beginning, otherwise - it will be ignored anyway.